# Changing EF in ASP.NET to work with SQLite instead of SQL Server

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, entity-framework, sqlite

I have a simple ASP.NET MVC 5 application simulating Movie rental store. I'm new to ASP.NET and course I'm following shows EF and migrations to local SQL Server database, meanwhile I have to use SQLite.

I've used nuget package manager, added SQLite to the project and reference to it appeared. What I don't understand and can't find online is what code to use in order to redirect EF to create SQLite tables instead of MS SQL ones?

I've enabled migrations, got migrations folder, but in its `Configuration.cs` file, I don't see anything related to SQL Server.

Comment: In EF7 support for SQL server compact has been dropped and a new provider for SQLite is being developed by the EF team. The provider will use Microsoft's managed SQLite wrapper project, Microsoft.Data.SQLite rather than the System.Data.SQLite project.

Comment: I'm using EF 6 version in my project.

Comment: Unfortunately, the EF6 provider implementation in System.Data.SQLite.EF6 doesn't support creating tables

Comment: So does that mean I won't be able just to create tables and will need to make them outside of VS in order to manipulate with them?

Comment: Yes. You can use DB Browser for SQLite and create the tables in it

Comment: Correct, no code first support with SQLite. You can use the "SQLite Toolbox" within Visual Studio to create and manage your SQLite database files.

Comment: OK, thank you Javed and Erik! Can you answer my question from OP? After I create the database with all the necessary tables, how to "link" it to my project and match classes from my project to corresponding tables in SQLite database?

Comment: Why do you need to use SQLLite?

Comment: I don't explicitly need to use SQLite, just a server-less database. Since nobody replied and I couldn't find anything online how to connect it, I decided to swtich to SQL Server Compact.

Comment: Good call, Mark, there is a SQL Server Compact provider for EF6 and EF Core, both support Code First